# c# awaitable task staying in the same context

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

Here is what I have:

- a multi-platform (Xamarin/C#) application
- an interface that defines a method (for a UI task) that has platform specific implementations
- on one platform the implementation needs to await some async calls, on the other one - it does not

My implementation:

- the interface defines the method as: Task DoSomething()
- on the platform where the implementation has to await async calls

The method is implemented as:

```
async Task DoSomething()
{
  // code
  await // async();
  // code
}
```

and that works fine

- on the platform where the implementation does not call other async methods I have 2 options:

  1. define the method as **async Task DoSomething()** and get a compile time warning "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously..."
  2. define the method as **Task DoSomething()** that returns Task.Run(() => { /*main logic here*/}), however when I call await DoSomething() - the main logic is executed on another thread, which I don't want to happen. With the implementation in (1) calling await DoSomething stays on the same thread.

How do I resolve this - return an awaitable task that is not async and stays on the same thread/context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `return Task.FromResult(returnValueHere)`. It will be slightly faster and will stay in the same thread.  And don't forget to remove `async` from the method declaration.

If your method returns nothing, you can also simply use `return Task.FromResult(0)`.

```
public Task DoSomething()
{
    // Work done here
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```